# Event handling in producer consumer model

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, event-handling, vsto

So I have 2 modules- WebserviceClientmodule for reading the data from a web service and ExcelModule to write the data fetched by the WebserviceClientmodule into excel sheet.So I have an event exposed at the WebserviceClientmodule and the ExcelModule subscribing to it.What my question is,is it the right way to do it because if ExcelModule is slower than WebserviceClientmodule,then how do I synchronize these two process? Or is there any other better way to implement this kind of produer consumer problem so that even if the data being fetched from the web service is faster,It doesnt cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you need. Since you only seem to have two threads running that are working with the same sets of data, I would use the ReadWriterLockSlim class, however using the Monitor class or Mutexs are also possible. The easiest to implement in my opinion is the ReadWriterLockSlim class.

For more information on ReadWriterLockSlim:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx